# How to optimally calculate all the possible solutions to a dot product with 1 unknown vector where the answer must ∈ Z+

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, algorithms

If I have a vector a=(9,14) and b=(x,y) their dot product equals 41 what are the possible solutions if any given that x and y must be Integers ∈ Z+, I am aware that the problem has infinite solutions in R

> an example on the problem would be : At a chicken nuggets store you can order either package of 9 nuggets or package of 14 package and a client came in and wanted to have 41, the answer should be you should get 1 package of 14 pieces, 3 packages of 9 pieces

the algorithm I want should consider higher dimensions and many solutions

my first approach was to try all combinations but i was wondering if someone has a more optimal approach to the problem.

Comment: What you want is the solution to  the linear diophantine equation

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation

Comment: yes thank you very very much, I didn't know the name or that it exists but that's precisely what I wanted.

Comment: For more variables, you will need some know how on matrix manipulation to construct the algorithm, but the two variable case is easy to set up with recursion

Comment: I am trying to make a general solution for higher dimension which is computationally efficient.

Comment: What does that mean? That is an arbitrary aim. You want it in polynomial time?

Comment: I didn't study the problem well enough to answer this question but hopeful I  will try to make logarithmic time algorithm.